# Call a Python script from another Python script with list as argument?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a Python script a.py from another Python script scheduler.py and I want to pass a list as argument something like:

Scheduler.py:

```
t = {"code": 161123134, "name": "task2", "domain": "www.google.com", "type": "Type1", "keywords": ["bai2", "yin4", "jiao3", "yi8", "ping1", "tai3"]}

hourTasks = json.dumps(t)
os.system("python a.py " + hourTasks)
```

a.py

```
task = sys.argv[1:]
task = json.loads(task)
```

However It gives me an error **the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'**. Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: It might be easier to do a bit of rewriting to `a.py`, and use it as a module instead. Otherwise, consider using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system()`.

Comment: The error is unrelated to running a Python script from another script. `task` in `json.loads(task)` is a list, not a string.

Comment: You want `sys.argv[1]` (the first argument), not `sys.argv[1:]` (a list containing the first, and any other, arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Scheduler.py:

```
import json
import subprocess

t = {"code": 161123134, "name": "task2", "domain": "www.google.com", "type": "Type1", "keywords": ["bai2", "yin4", "jiao3", "yi8", "ping1", "tai3"]}

task = json.dumps(t)
subprocess.call(["python", "a.py", task])
```

a.py:

```
import json
import sys                                                                                        

task = sys.argv[1]
t = json.loads(task)
```

Answer (score 0):

from one script you should import the other and there is no need to use json between your two scripts, just pass an python dict instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method of the dicts, to read the keys and the values. And before that do a counter and membership check like. For x in xs: